# failes to find "true" in mail to range macro

Tags: vba, excel

Got a macro from **Ron de Bruin** which I've been using, but now I can't get it to find the "TRUE" in the reference column. **The "TRUE" is generated from checkboxes, it works if I write "yes"** I've used the original code from his page, shown here:

```
Sub Test1()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Office 2000-2016
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _ 'right value is being shown
       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value) = "TRUE" Then 'suddenly skips this phase. 
                                            'Shows the right row but nothing happens anymore

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Reminder"
            .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                    "your account up to date"
            'You can add files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Display  'Or use Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If I remove `And _ LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value) = "TRUE"` it works like a charm. I hope someone can help me out with this.

Comment: do you still have that error with the edited code and `UCase()`? If so, show us the code that writes `True` (or `False`?) into cells

Comment: @user3598756 As mentioned in the org post the "TRUE" is generated from checkboxes

Comment: I've read that, that's why I asked for the specific code that writes in cells

Comment: @user3598756 It's a standard checkbox With the only reference to the same cell as its in. From each click you either get "TRUE" or "FALSE", no special formula in that cell.
Only thing I see is that no matter if I use the checkbox or write "true" in a cell it get centred and in capital letters. I think that causes the fault, but I don't get why?!

Comment: being the cell linked to a (ActiveX) CheckBox control, its value is a of `Boolean` type so just use it as such - see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the cell whose value you're querying is linked to a (ActiveX) checkbox its value is of a `Boolean` type

so you have to check it as such, that is:

```
If Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value Then  'means IF Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value = True
```

Comment: Thx. Gonna give that a shot in the morning. Sounds to be the correct thing

Comment: Glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

The following line is incorrect

```
LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value) = "TRUE" Then
```

you are converting the value to lowercase using the `LCase` function (eg `true`) ... you should change it to

```
UCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value) = "TRUE" Then
```